# Como colocar simbolo de moneda respetando numberformat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema al enviar los datos desde mi aplicación, puesto que cuando hago un promedio y lo convierto a string el formato queda con la moneda de mi país de la siguiente manera: 
        PEN7,623.50

Debido a que es una lista me gustaría cambiar el PEN por un "S/. " o dejarlo vacío pero respetando los valores ",/." del número formateado. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    public String getPromedio() {

        double valuea,valueb,valuec,valued,valuee;
        valuea = Double.parseDouble(periodo1);
        valueb = Double.parseDouble(periodo2);
        valuec = Double.parseDouble(periodo3);
        valued = Double.parseDouble(periodo4);
        valuee = valuea+valueb+valuec+valued/4;
        NumberFormat pen_promedio = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        pen_promedio.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("PEN"));
       // promedio = String.format("%.2f", valuee);
        promedio = pen_promedio.format(valuee);

        return promedio;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes setear un símbolo de moneda personalizado haciendo algo así: `DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("S/. "); ((DecimalFormat) pen_promedio).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs); promedio = pen_promedio.format(valuee);` Está de más decir que esta línea tendrías que borrarla: `pen_promedio.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("PEN"));`

Comment: excelente amigo me funcionó perfecto muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @G.Romero si la respuesta de A.Cedano te ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, recuerda marcarla como solución, revisa [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase `DecimalFormatSymbols` para personalizar el símbolo de moneda que quieres mostrar.

```
NumberFormat pen_promedio = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(); 
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("S/. "); 
((DecimalFormat) pen_promedio).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs); 
promedio = pen_promedio.format(valuee);
```

La clase tiene más métodos interesantes, si quieres cambiar el separador de miles, de decimales, etc.

Si quieres que aparezca sin símbolo de moneda sólo haces esto:

```
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("");
```

Y si quieres que aparezca con la palabra "Pepe", ya sabes lo que habría que hacer:)

### Enlaces

- [Tutorial de Oracle sobre formatos personalizados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)
- [La clase `DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html)

Comment: Una duda adicional, en el emulador el simbolo aparece delante del numero lo cual me parece perfecto, pero debido a mi país al instalarlo en mi celular el simbolo aparece al final del numero. Como puedo mantener la posición del símbolo delante del número?

Comment: @G.Romero es una pregunta interesante. Sería mejor que abras una nueva pregunta planteando esta duda, así tendrá más visibilidad y mayor posibilidad de respuestas, pudiendo ser de utilidad para futuros usuarios que tengan la misma duda. Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas.